# Create dynamically php page based on the count of json objects response

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, object

I have a json as an array of objects.(response of API)

I am using PHP as SSR (server side rendering)

I was wondering if I can make php page dynamically and write in based on the count of object array?

For example: having 3 object into an array I have a url:

> localhost:9000/result.php (which having boxes of results and while clicking)

it create and load to

> localhost:9000/result.php/&count=1
>
> localhost:9000/result.php/&count=2
>
> localhost:9000/result.php/&count=3

Here is what i have done

the json:

```
    {lenght:3,names:[{name:jack},{name:brian},{name:mike}]}
```

the php code  result.php:

```
      $ch = curl_init();  

     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"localhost:9000/names");
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 

     $output=curl_exec($ch);

     $count=$output->lenght;
     for ($i=0;$i<count;$i++){
      $my_file = 'result'.$count.'php';
      $handle = fopen($result, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$result);
   }
     $data ="i don't know what to do here " ;
      fwrite($handle, $data);
       }
```

in `data` i don't know how to load the json field based on the `$count`

so that in :
result1.php i have  jack
result2.php i have  brian
result3.php i have  mike

Could someone, please, help?

Thanks for any suggestions or insights.

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth here is what i have tried thanks for the help

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php